# Upload ePub file from ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, epub

Currently, I am uploading PDF files, and images from my MVC web application to a sql server database. This works perfectly, however I now want to be able to upload ePub files.

I tried to do it with the same uploader in some vain hope that it would work, however this is the error I get:

> SqlException was unhandled by the user
>   code.
>
> "The parameterized query
>   '(@FileContent varbinary(max)
>   ,@MimeType nvarchar(4000),@FileName'
>   expects the parameter '@MimeType',
>   which was not supplied.

Here is also the code from my controller which handles the uploads:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

    foreach (string upload in Request.Files)
    {
        if (!Request.Files[upload].HasFile1()) continue;

        string mimeType = Request.Files[upload].ContentType;
        Stream fileStream = Request.Files[upload].InputStream;
        string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Request.Files[upload].FileName);
        int fileLength = Request.Files[upload].ContentLength;
        byte[] fileData = new byte[fileLength];
        fileStream.Read(fileData, 0, fileLength);

        const string connect = @"Server=localhost;Database=Images;user id=taraw; password=****;";
        using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            var qry = "INSERT INTO FileStore (FileContent, MimeType, FileName) VALUES (@FileContent, @MimeType, @FileName)";
            var cmd = new SqlCommand(qry, conn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileContent", fileData);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MimeType", mimeType);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FileName", fileName);
            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }

    return View();
}
```

I know the error is pretty self explanatory as to what the problem is, I'm just unsure how to modify the code to allow it to accept ePub File formats.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: On a side note, iterating over `Request.Files` is not the ASP.NET MVC way to do it. You should use the built-in model binding facilities that handle file uploads. Otherwise, you will run into portability and testability problems.

Comment: Thanks bzlm, I will take note of this. I've followed this from a tutorial but I do realise there's a lot of room for improvement.

Comment: The tutorials on asp.net/mvc are great. I'm guessing the one you used isn't from there. :) http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-mvc-part1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that the mimetype for an epub file is application / epub + zip. Specified this in my application rather than expecting it from the user and this seems to have done the trick. File is uploading and downloading without any issues.

Thanks to anyone who commented :)

Answer (score 0):

Add ePUB into your server's Mime type list as a known type, i guess mime-type is going null into db, that's why this error getting raised up.

Comment: Hi Mazhar! Thanks for the reply. Currently I'm working locally on my laptop. Do you know how to configure visual studio's settings to accept ePub as a mime type?

Comment: @Mazhar In the code, the mime-type is supplied by the client in `Request.Files[upload].ContentType`. Your suggestion would require some major refactoring.

Comment: @Tara The problem is that the mime-type isn't supplied by the client, or that the uploaded file is broken or missing information in some other way. You should not rely on clients to supply the mime-type, since this is likely to vary depending on browser.

Comment: @blzm, thats for the link. No the tutorial wasn't from there ;-) I will take a look :) Not sure they are likely to solve my ePub problem though :-S I'm just not sure how to handle this file type at all.